# Filtering Parsed Data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, json

Here is an example of the JSON I am getting before it is parsed:

```
[{"_id":"5b9d3a46793d8d18feec7951","key":"___","list":["___"]}
```

If I wanted to show only a part of it, how would I do that? I was trying something like:

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
console.log(data.key)
```

Answer (score 0):

data is coming as a array you have to use index like 0,1,2...n to get particular index data key.

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText) console.log(data[0].key)
```

or you want print all key of all data in array then use forEach

```
data.forEach(function(val,i){
  console.log(val.key);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is wrong and I have modified and you can parse the value as below

```js
var value = [
  {
    "id": "5b9d3a46793d8d18feec7951",
    "key": "",
    "list": [
      "_"
    ]
  }
];

console.log(value[0].id);
console.log(value[0].key);
```